# Trouble with jQuery loop through array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to nest 3 divs within a "row" div.

I had this working in "long format" (multiple var's instead of looping through the array). I've refactored my code and now I don't get any error codes AND my code does not append to the HTML file. When I console log I get an array with 3 objects. I'm sure i'm missing something minor.

Anyways some help would be great!

```
 <div class="row">
   **nested divs go here.
 </div>
```

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?id4726206&cnt=3", {
            APPID: "MY API KEY",
            lat: 29.423017,
            lon: -98.48527,
            units: "imperial"
        }).done(function(data) {

            var stationId = data.city.name;

            // Stattion Name
            $('#station').append(stationId);

            //console.log(data);
            var forecast = data.list;

            //Wind Direction in Compass Format
            function getDirection(dir) {
                var compass = ['N', 'NNE', 'NE', 'ENE', 'E', 'ESE', 'SE', 'SSE', 'S', 'SSW', 'SW', 'WSW', 'W', 'WNW', 'NW', 'NNW'];
                var result = Math.floor((360 - dir) / 22.5);
                return compass[result];
            }

            //Forecast Variables

            $.each(forecast, function(i, v) {
                var html = '';
                html += "<div class='col-sm-3 wInfo'>" + "<div class='title'>High / Low</div>";
                html += "<div class='cTemp'>" + (Math.ceil(forecast[i].temp.max)) + '&deg;';
                html += " / " + (Math.ceil(forecast[i].temp.min)) + '&deg;' + "</div>";
                html += "<div class='tempIcon'>" + "<img src='http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + forecast[i].weather[0].icon;
                html += ".png' alt=''></div>" + "<div class='conditions' id='castId'>" + '<span class="cond">' + forecast[i].weather[0].main;
                html += "</span>: " + "<span>" + forecast[i].weather[0].description + '</span>' + "</div>";
                html += "<div class='conditions'>" + "<span class='cond'>Humidity: </span>" + "<span>" + forecast[i].humidity + "&#37;</span></div>";
                html += "<div class='conditions'>" + "<span class='cond'>Wind: </span>" + "<span>" + (Math.floor(forecast[i].speed));
                html += " mph / " + getDirection(forecast[i].deg) + "</span></div>" + "<div class='conditions'>";
                html += "<span class='cond'>Pressure: </span>" + "<span>" + forecast[i].pressure + "</span></div>";
                return html;


            });
            $('.forecast').append(forecast);
            console.log(forecast);

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to append the array forecast in html. which wont work. You should declare the html variable outside and then use it in append function.

I will also recommend to use string builder logic using array and then convert it to string and append it. remember string concatenation is heavy operator as it creates new instance of elememt every time concatenation is done :

```
var html = [];
$.each(forecast, function(i, v) {
            html.push("<div class='col-sm-3 wInfo'>" + "<div class='title'>High / Low</div>");
            html.push("<div class='cTemp'>" + (Math.ceil(forecast[i].temp.max)) + '&deg;');
            html.push(" / " + (Math.ceil(forecast[i].temp.min)) + '&deg;' + "</div>");
            html.push("<div class='tempIcon'>" + "<img src='http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + forecast[i].weather[0].icon);
            html.push(".png' alt=''></div>" + "<div class='conditions' id='castId'>" + '<span class="cond">' + forecast[i].weather[0].main);
            html.push("</span>: " + "<span>" + forecast[i].weather[0].description + '</span>' + "</div>");
            html.push("<div class='conditions'>" + "<span class='cond'>Humidity: </span>" + "<span>" + forecast[i].humidity + "&#37;</span></div>");
            html.push("<div class='conditions'>" + "<span class='cond'>Wind: </span>" + "<span>" + (Math.floor(forecast[i].speed)));
            html.push(" mph / " + getDirection(forecast[i].deg) + "</span></div>" + "<div class='conditions'>");
            html.push("<span class='cond'>Pressure: </span>" + "<span>" + forecast[i].pressure + "</span></div></div>");
        });

 $('.forecast').append(html.join(""));
```

Comment: Very insightful. Thanks! I'll bear this in mind before I concat my strings. :thumbsUp:

Comment: Just as an odd observation. I noticed that the 3 nested divs are nesting within each other. So the 3 div is nested inside the 2nd which is nested inside the 1st? Perhaps I'm missing something in the html.push? Edit** I was missing a closing div.

Comment: @cpt-crunchy: nop. looks good to me. can you create a problem fiddle. it will be easy to debug and fix there

Comment: Are you asking that I make a fiddle instead of posting static code? I'll do that instead. Unless your asking me to make a fiddle of this.